# Can't call Click Event on dynamic button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I want to create a method in code behind that creates a button and places it in a PlaceHolder.  I want this button to have a Click event.

After calling the "test" method button is placed correctly but the click event is not called.

```
private void test()
    {
        Button linkBtn1 = new Button();
        linkBtn1.Text = "linkBtn1";
        linkBtn1.OnClientClick = "return false;";
        linkBtn1.Click += new EventHandler(linkBtn1_Click);
        PagesPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(linkBtn1);          

    }

    void linkBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: maybe because of this line `linkBtn1.OnClientClick = "return false;";
`?

Comment: its not maybe, its for sure, remove the OnClientClick, or if you like to return something to overwrite other behaviour, return true to let it click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the `OnClientClick = "return false;"` is necessary but not sufficient to get this to work.  If you want the event handler on the dynamically added button to be triggered, you'll need to add this button **every time the page loads**.

One simple way would be to save the fact that the button has been added in ViewState, and then check that on PageLoad, and re-add the button if needed.

Here's a sample that works for me (and throws the exception when clicked)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if the button was added previously, add it again
    if (ViewState["Added"] != null && (bool)ViewState["Added"])
        addButton();
}

//this is the method that adds the button
protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ViewState["Added"] = true;
    addButton();
}

private void addButton() {
    Button linkBtn1 = new Button();
    linkBtn1.Text = "linkBtn1";
    linkBtn1.Click += new EventHandler(linkBtn1_Click);
    placeholder1.Controls.Add(linkBtn1);
}

void linkBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    throw new Exception("Button Click Event Triggered.  Hello yellow screen!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @oleksii points out, have the clientside code is returning false so the form never gets submitted. You need to comment this out, then your event handler should fire.